# Storing an ASCII value into a std::string

Tags: c++

Currently writing some C++ code that stores an ASCII value (65) into a `std::string`.

Which of the following is more idiomatic C++ code or common?

```
result += static_cast<char>(value); // Explicit int to char
result += value;                    // Implicit int to char
```

The expected output is `AA`.

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1d7KTa88r)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string result;
    int value = 65; // ASCII value for 'A'

    result += static_cast<char>(value); // Explicit int to char
    result += value;                    // Implicit int to char

    std::cout << result << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Internally, both lines of code generate the same instructions.

[image: ascii]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the expected and actual output.

Comment: And why not `char value = 'A';`? Or even `int value = 'A';` if you're required to use an `ìnt` for some reason (and then please include that requirement when you update your question).

Comment: Which of the two approaches is best is a matter of opinion, neither is strictly better or more idiomatic than the other. You could say using `static_cast` clarifies the intent, and you could say it adds clutter reducing readability. Neither is incorrect.

Comment: And generally, don't store "ASCII" (or other encoding variant) values in a string, store *characters*. `'A'` is portable, `65` is not.

Comment: Agree with @FrançoisAndrieux: `static_cast` is somewhat cluttering, but more clear (and still safe). As long as you're not using C-style casts (e.g. `result += (char)value;`) or equivalently dangerous (and more verbose) C++ versions thereof (e.g. `reinterpret_cast`), both versions are safe (if `value`'s type isn't compatible with `char` it won't silently do terrible things like interpret low bytes of a pointer as `char`), and there's no arguments for one or the other that boil down to anything beyond "Do you want to be explicit and ugly (aiding weaker C++ maintainers) or implicit and pretty?"

Comment: The idiomatic way is `'A'`. Numbers will only work for the *US-ASCII* range, 0x00-07F, which is common across all codepages but can't cover all English words, eg  `naïve`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: You're making a distinction that is misleading/incorrect. There is no distinction between ASCII and US-ASCII. The latter is a synonym for the former that IANA likes to use, but they both mean the same range of values from 0x00-0x7F. Any values above 0x7F would be in what are sometimes called "ASCII superset encodings" or "extended ASCII encodings" (Microsoft liking the term "codepages", as you mention), where they assign locale dependent meaning to 0x80-0xFF, but none of those are ASCII (0x80-0xFF have no meaning whatsoever in ASCII).

Comment: Since both ways are the same, this boils down to style and preferences, which is subjective or bound by clauses in the company coding standards. And thus really off-topic.

Comment: @ShadowRanger give me a way to say this *in a single word* that avoids nitpickers saying `This is ANSI not ASCII` or `This is ASCII not ANSI* and can be easily understood by people confusing Latin1 or ISO-8859-1 with ASCII

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Your original comment (before editing) made a distinction between ASCII and US-ASCII, which is what I was responding to. The edited comment, that only mentions US-ASCII (without contrasting it with ASCII as if they're different things) seems fine; the "US-" isn't *technically* necessary, but it does avoid nitpickers and avoid the ignorant who can't distinguish ASCII from its supersets.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've answered so, so many questions about mangled text, mojibake or worse, lost data that *both* make me cringe. Including the `but LC_ALL` excuse that fails as soon as people have to read data with a different encoding. Like the German data scientist on a Mac a while back that tried to analyze Russian data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would always use the most clear option:

```
result += static_cast<char>(value);
```

This shows the clear intent.

Comment: Recently tried converting C code to idiomatic C++ and wasn't sure which syntax to use. I eventually coded it as you suggested since it's explicit and no ambiguity imo. Thanks!

Comment: No machine uses a 7-bit encoding. What happens when this *ambiguous* code inevitably encounters a value above 0x7F ? Even English words use characters outside that range

Comment: In my test case, it's dealing only with bytes which are are 8 bits and represents 256 values (0 through 255 integers).

Comment: @vengy: Even assuming an ASCII base, values from 128-255 have locale-dependent meaning (one meaning on a Western European locale, another on a Russian locale, yet another on an Arabic locale, etc., and that's before we get into multibyte ASCII-superset encodings like UTF-8). Beyond that, `char` has implementation-defined signedness, so those values may not even exist, being represented by negative numbers instead. ASCII (also known as US-ASCII) only handles 0 through 127, with byte values outside that range having no meaning at all.